# POI ignoring some snippets of docx

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi, docx

I'm trying to use this code (POI 3.11) to extract text from a docx file:

```
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("sample.docx"));
        for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
            List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
            if (runs != null) {
                for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                    String text = r.getText(0);
                    System.out.println(text);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the document.xml file inside the sample.docx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
                <w:rPr/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="__DdeLink__59_1605705532"/>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr/>
                <w:t>A</w:t>     // THIS PRINT!
                <w:tab/>
                <w:t>B</w:t>     // THIS IS NOT! WHY?!
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr>
            <w:type w:val="nextPage"/>
            <w:pgSz w:h="16838" w:w="11906"/>
            <w:pgMar w:bottom="1134" w:footer="0" w:gutter="0" w:header="0" w:left="1134" w:right="1134" w:top="1134"/>
            <w:pgNumType w:fmt="decimal"/>
            <w:formProt w:val="false"/>
            <w:textDirection w:val="lrTb"/>
            <w:docGrid w:charSpace="4294961151" w:linePitch="240" w:type="default"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

When I run the code, this result the follow:

`A`

I don't understand why, but for unknown reasons, some snippets (letter B) from text are ignored (If I open the file using LibreOffice, it's showing successfully).

Comment: Are you only interested in printing out the contents of the run? If so, [XWPFRun.text()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#text%28%29) is probably what you want to call - that handles converting newlines / tabs / etc into their text equivalents and returns the whole run as a string

Comment: Oddly, I couldn't find this method in class XWPFRun... but XWPFParagraph.getText() do the same... However I access the text in "run level" in order to change it from old to a new content.

Comment: Try upgrading then - looks like that was added in Apache POI 3.12 beta 1, or try using XWPFRun.toString() for something roughly similar on 3.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this link (http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/POI-3-10-1-XWPFRun-getText-Does-Not-Return-Full-Line-of-Text-tp5716539p5716541.html), I figured out that each paragraph may have multiples runs (snippets of text) and each one may have a different style or no, depending on the history of the file.

In this issue, the file has one paragraph with two snippets of text. In `String text = r.getText(0)` I caught only one of them.

How I couldn't find in API a method that returns all snippets of a paragraph, I need to do a workaround to solve:

```
if (runs != null) {
    for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                String text = r.getText(i);

                if (text == null) {
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println(text);
                i++;
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                break;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

I hope this can help someone a day!